# Translate R to Python pipeline - filter, select and sort

Tags: python, pandas

I'm cleaning up a dataset in R, and am trying to find equivalent of my below cleaning process in Python.

```
df = dataframe %>% 
  filter(grepl('abc', Sheet1)) %>% 
  select(product) %>% 
  arrange(nchar(product))
```

I know for filtering in Pandas I can do something like df[df['var'] != 'string'], but how can I do it if I want specific string values contained and select relevant columns before sorting?

Any insights will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: dt = dt0 %>% 
    filter( grepl( 'Illinois', States) ) %>% 
    select(
      population, crime rate
    ) %>% 
    arrange( nchar(populaiton) ) So I basically I was trying to filter out non-Illinois states and then select population and crime rate for cities while sorting by city population. It works for me in R but I couldn't get a proper code to run in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sheet1':['abc f','as abc','ss','abc','abcd'],
                   'product':['aa','sss','aaa','s','ddddd'],
                   'val':[7,8,9,4,2]})

print (df)
   Sheet1 product  val
0   abc f      aa    7
1  as abc     sss    8
2      ss     aaa    9
3     abc       s    4
4    abcd   ddddd    2
```

---

```
df = df[df['Sheet1'].str.contains('abc')]
print (df)
   Sheet1 product  val
0   abc f      aa    7
1  as abc     sss    8
2      ss     aaa    9
3     abc       s    4
4    abcd   ddddd    2

df = df.iloc[df['product'].str.len().argsort()]
print (df)
   Sheet1 product  val
3     abc       s    4
0   abc f      aa    7
1  as abc     sss    8
4    abcd   ddddd    2

df = df[['product','val']]
print (df)
  product  val
3       s    4
0      aa    7
1     sss    8
4   ddddd    2
```

Comment: @CatherineZhang - I add some sample data, give em a sec.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you can post data, but roughly:

```
> df %>% filter(grepl('abc', Sheet1)) %>%
```

df.Sheet1.str.contains('abc')

```
> select(product) %>%
```

...just subscript by ['product']...

```
> arrange(nchar(product))
```

df.sort_index(level=df.product.apply(len))

Comment: Thanks! I think 'select' can also be df[['population', 'crime rate']].